# Problema al conectarse a MS Access con Java: Resultset.next() siempre devuelve false

Tags: java, ms-access

Tengo el siguiente método para establecer la conexión en un Access:

```
public boolean establecerConexion() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    try{
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        String database = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"+nombre_bd+";";
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(database);
    }catch (SQLException e){
        logger.error("Error al realizar la conexion "+e);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Y después de establecer la conexión ejecuto la sentencia sql:

```
public void ejecutarSentencia(String sql) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try
    {
        if(this.establecerConexion())
        {
            Statement s = conexion.createStatement();
            s.executeQuery(sql);
            rs = s.getResultSet();
            while((rs!=null) && (rs.next()))
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }

            rs.close();
            s.close();
            conexion.close();
        }

    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        logger.error("Se ha producido un error al ejecutar la query. " + e.getMessage()+ ". " + e.getCause());
    }
}
```

Al ejecutar el método establecerConexion() no da ningún tipo de problema. Al ejecutar la query "sql" por fuera no da ningún problema y devuelve resultados.

Mi problema es que la sentencia rs.next() siempre devuelve false. ¿A qué es debido?